# Automatically find out Dependency DLLs

Tags: dll, dependencies

We ran into a problem where at development time when developer updates any NuGet and some of the dependencies are automatically added at compile time so, the updates run fine on developer machine (because the new dependencies are automatically copied by VS in bin folder). But when the same code goes through the build process and when QA tries to test the build, then it does not work because newly added dependencies are not installed.

So, I am looking for some tool or some technique that can automatically report that there are new dependencies that needs to be added into installer.

Thanks!

I know about Dependency Waker and some reflections tools like ILSpy using which we can identify are the dependencies of one particular DLL, but I cannot think of how I can automate it?